# Проблемы с кириллицей в notepad++

Tags: кодировка, utf-8, notepad++

Имеем: `Notepad++` версии `6.7.9.2` и установленный плагин `DBGp 0.0.13.27`

Кодировка везде настроена `utf-8` (`notepad`, `denver`, `mysql`, ...), но в дебаггере кириллические символы отображаются как `"РљРѕР»-РІРѕ"`. Как с этим бороться?

Comment: Не пользоваться нотпадом, там вечно какие-то проблемы с кодировкой :)

Comment: а какие предложения по легковесной IDE без монстрообразной java? `php / js / css / html` ?

Comment: Sublime например